# Issues with implementing checksum bits on a custom protocol in ruby

Tags: ruby, serial-port, byte, protocols

I have the following protocol spec for sending messages to a device i am integrating with, divided into bytes,by order:

1. Binary 0x02 Start byte
2. ASCII '1' or '2' or '3' or '4' Device address
3. ASCII '0' - No change '1' - Change output Load output change
4. ASCII 'E' – Boost voltage set 'D' – Discharge voltage set 'T' – Temperature compensation set 'C' – Max.
5. ASCII '0' – No change '-' - Selected value change down '+'
6. Binary s=(byte)SUM(2;5) CRC_H=0b1000_s7_s6_s5_s4 Checksum hight byte
7. Binary s=(byte)SUM(2;5) CRC_L=0b1000_s3_s2_s1_s0 Checksum low byte
8. Binary 0x03

I am having trouble getting bytes 6 & 7 correctly.

It is not very clear how to calculate the checksum, it says byte 6 and 7 are a sum of (2;5) - what does 2;5 mean?

the code i have currently is:

```
require 'serialport'

# Open collector serial port
serial = SerialPort.new('/dev/ttyAMA0', baud: 9600, data_bits: 8, stop_bits: 1,
  parity: SerialPort::NONE)

checksum = '10E0'.unpack("C*").inject(:+).ord
p serial.write(0x02.chr) # start byte
p serial.write('10E0') # commands
p serial.write(checksum + checksum) # checksum byte 1 + 2
p serial.write(0x03.chr) # End byte
p serial.read
```

no luck with a response. does anybody have an idea what am i doing wrong? or a better understanding for this spec?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take two aspirins and then have a look at [Array#pack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [String#unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-unpack).

Comment: Thank you for that, how would I write the 1101 and 0110 as a single byte? - I tried 1101.ord but that says `chr': 1101 out of char range (RangeError)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my original comment, so I deleted it and will add a corrected version below. I'm not familiar with `SerialPort`, so you'll have to check the docs to see how to write the bytes `0x0` and `0xD6`.

Comment: It appears that #5 could be the ASCII value for "0", "-" or "+" but there are only two descriptors ("No change" and "- Selected value change down"). Please clarify. I presume "sum of (2;5)" means the sum of the bytes for #2-#5. The sum of 4 bytes may be a number requiring 2 bytes; hence, the need for #6 and #7. `t = ('1'.ord+'0'.ord+'E'.ord+'0'.ord) #=> 214; t.to_s(16) #=> "D6"` gives the hex representation of the sum of four possible values for #2-#5. Since this fits into a single byte, the high-order byte is `0` and the low-order byte, is `0xD6`.

Comment: I'm trying this based on the above, but still getting no response :(

`p serial.write(0x02.chr) # start byte`
`p serial.write('10E0') # commands`
`p serial.write(0x0.chr) # Checksum 1`
`p serial.write(0xD6.chr) # Checksum 2`
`p serial.write(0x03.chr) # End byte`
`p serial.read`

Comment: Perhaps another reader can take it from here. yonigozman, you haven't answered my question about #5.

Comment: Thank you for trying - much appreciated :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland - sorry for #5, the 3rd descriptor is '+' - Selected value change up

Answer (score 3):

Your *"protocol spec"* is confusing. For bytes 6&7 it mentions both *"checksum"* and *"CRC"*. Those are two different types of calculations. They are not synonymous. Checksum is prone to false validations when there are multiple bit errors. CRC is much better at detecting errors.

So you need to resolve the question of whether you need to calculate the CRC-8 check value or the checksum (truncated to one byte) of message bytes 2 through 5.  Regardless you would end up with an 8-bit value to be stored in message bytes 6&7.

Your *"protocol spec"* has:

```
6. Binary s=(byte)SUM(2;5) CRC_H=0b1000_s7_s6_s5_s4 Checksum hight byte
7. Binary s=(byte)SUM(2;5) CRC_L=0b1000_s3_s2_s1_s0 Checksum low byte
```

Apparently the high nibble of the checksum byte (i.e. bits *"s7_s6_s5_s4"*) is stored in byte 6 of the message with the high bit (bit 8) set (as indicated by the *"0b1000_"* bit string).  The low nibble of the checksum byte (i.e. bits *"s3_s2_s1_s0"*) is stored in byte 7 of the message with the high bit (bit 8) set.

Presumably setting bit 8 (in each byte) will prevent false detection of the message's start or end byte whenever the checksum results in a value of 0x02 or 0x03.  This should improve message integrity by making the message frame easy to identity and difficult to misidentify.

I don't do ruby, so can only offer C code.

```
unsigned char chksum = mesg[2] + mesg[3] + mesg[4] + mesg[5];
mesg[6] = 0x80 | ((chksum >> 4) & 0x0f);
mesg[7] = 0x80 | (chksum & 0x0f);
```